# Web App Manifest: hash in start_url

Tags: angularjs, url, web, url-routing, manifest

Is there a way to set the hash in a web app manifest ? 
Something like that:

```
"start_url": "/#/admin",
```

I tried it but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Comment: is this not a /#admin?

Comment: I tried with "start_url": "/", but can't pass the audit... Looking for this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this: `"start_url": "./"`

Pay attention that all links are relative to the manifest file, meaning if your manifest is in /assets folder, you need to return to root to get that index.html file.